# 5 out of 6 popups(modals) showing up,1 hangs up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm again stuck on another problem. I put 6 popups, but the last one is showing but hangs up the screen and i have to refresh and get out of it. I tried to match the codes with the ones that are correct but i find no difference.

This is the one that is working:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
                                    <div class="item-instructor bg-color-5">
                                        <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
                                            <img src="img/saif.jpg" data-at2x="img/saif.jpg" alt>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="info-box">
                                            <h3>M saifur Rahman</h3>
                                            <span class="instructor-profession">CBAP pro</span>
                                            <div class="divider"></div>
<center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">M saifur Rahman</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="biography-image">
                                <img src="img/saif.jpg" align="left">
                            </div>
               <div class="biography-info">
                    <p></p>         

               </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And this is the code that is not working properly:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
                                    <div class="item-instructor bg-color-5">
                                        <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
                                            <img src="img/sazzad.jpg" data-at2x="img/sazzad.jpg" alt>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="info-box">
                                            <h3>M sazzad Hossain</h3>
                                            <span class="instructor-profession">CBAP pro</span>
                                            <div class="divider"></div>
<center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#func">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="func" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">M sazzad Hossain</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="biography-image">
                                <img src="img/sazzad.jpg" align="left">
                            </div>
               <div class="biography-info">
                    <p>At LightCastle Partners, Sazzad brings along a broad spectrum of experience. In his short but eventful career, Sazzad has worked in three distinctly different roles – a Management Trainee in Retail Financing, a Trade Marketer cum a Distribution Manager in Tobacco Industry, and a Lecturer in Management Studies. In all the roles, he has performed exceptionally well and demonstrated an ability to excel under trying circumstances. Sazzad started his career as an intern at HSBC. Upon completion, he joined another international organization – IPDC of Bangladesh Ltd. as a Management Trainee. At IPDC, he worked closely with the R&D team to develop new financial products and review performance of existing ones, and coordinated key accounts and branch activities. He joined British American Tobacco Bangladesh (BATB) as an Assistant Territory Officer in 2010. Developing product reinforcement campaigns and launching new brands, Sazzad helped modify BATB’s distribution structure to increase efficiency that eventually led to the capture of a greater market share. In 2012, he joined Heriot-Watt University, UK, as a lecturer in its distant learning program where he taught courses on International Strategic Management and Introduction to Business. Sazzad holds a bachelor’s in Accounting and Information Systems from University of Dhaka and is currently enrolled in MSc Marketing in the University of Manchester, UK. He is takes an active interest in travelling, European football, and religion.

</p>        

               </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

And the bootstrap/javascripts are given below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes the tried the same exact structure..okay i'm providing the javascript links..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are seeing, but this seems to work fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <div class="gallery-item">
    <div class="item-instructor bg-color-5">
      <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
        <img src="img/saif.jpg" data-at2x="img/saif.jpg" alt>
      </a>
      <div class="info-box">
        <h3>M saifur Rahman</h3>
        <span class="instructor-profession">CBAP pro</span>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button></center>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">M saifur Rahman</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="biography-image">
                  <img src="img/saif.jpg" align="left">
                </div>
                <div class="biography-info">
                  <p></p>

                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-item">
          <div class="item-instructor bg-color-5">
            <a href="page-profile.html" class="instructor-avatar">
              <img src="img/sazzad.jpg" data-at2x="img/sazzad.jpg" alt>
            </a>
            <div class="info-box">
              <h3>M sazzad Hossain</h3>
              <span class="instructor-profession">CBAP pro</span>
              <div class="divider"></div>
              <center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#func">Read More</button></center>
              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="func" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">M sazzad Hossain</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="biography-image">
                        <img src="img/sazzad.jpg" align="left">
                      </div>
                      <div class="biography-info">
                        <p>At LightCastle Partners, Sazzad brings along a broad spectrum of experience. In his short but eventful career, Sazzad has worked in three distinctly different roles – a Management Trainee in Retail Financing, a Trade Marketer cum
                          a Distribution Manager in Tobacco Industry, and a Lecturer in Management Studies. In all the roles, he has performed exceptionally well and demonstrated an ability to excel under trying circumstances. Sazzad started his career
                          as an intern at HSBC. Upon completion, he joined another international organization – IPDC of Bangladesh Ltd. as a Management Trainee. At IPDC, he worked closely with the R&D team to develop new financial products and review
                          performance of existing ones, and coordinated key accounts and branch activities. He joined British American Tobacco Bangladesh (BATB) as an Assistant Territory Officer in 2010. Developing product reinforcement campaigns and
                          launching new brands, Sazzad helped modify BATB’s distribution structure to increase efficiency that eventually led to the capture of a greater market share. In 2012, he joined Heriot-Watt University, UK, as a lecturer in its
                          distant learning program where he taught courses on International Strategic Management and Introduction to Business. Sazzad holds a bachelor’s in Accounting and Information Systems from University of Dhaka and is currently enrolled
                          in MSc Marketing in the University of Manchester, UK. He is takes an active interest in travelling, European football, and religion.

                        </p>

                      </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This works on the latest Chrome, FF, and IE 11 for me.